# Laravel - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: laravel

Делаю на локалке, не пойму при чем тут root ?

в конфиге прописал

```
 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('localhost'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'mysql'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'mysql'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Локальный сервер перезагружал...  кеш чистил php artisan config:clear

Что не так?

Comment: Вот отсель: `'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'mysql')`. Видимо, где-то в конфиге `DB_USERNAME = root`

Comment: Первое что я сделал - это поиск в конфиге по слову root - ничего, пусто

Comment: Что в файле `.env`?

Comment: Речь шла о конфигурационных файлах Laravel и PHP, а не о config.sys.

Comment: До этого я мучал файл database.php, благодаря совету E_K посмотрел .env, исправил так (да там был root), , спасибо, это помогло!

Answer (score 0):

в файле .env значение `DB_USERNAME=root` поменяйте на ваш username